# How to bind Kafka consumer to Storm spout?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

How to send Consumer record to Storm Spout object in one line code ? I have two instance one of them is KafkaConsumer object and other one is StormSpout object. I want to get nextTuple which came from Kafka Consumer poll to Spout using KafkaBolt object.

Comment: You need to produce into the topic that your Spout is subscribed to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe your understanding is a little wrong. You're not supposed to create a KafkaConsumer manually.

Use the KafkaSpout (or Trident spout) from the `org.apache.storm:storm-kafka-client` module. You can find guides on how to use it in the Storm documentation at https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/storm-kafka-client.html, and example code at https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-kafka-client-examples.